# PHP crypt() error

Tags: php, mysql

I read php.net manual about `crypt()` function. And here is my code:

```
#code.....
#we retrieve existing salt and password from database
$salt=$saltquery['salt'];
#$ex_password - existing password
$ex_password=$saltquery['pass'];
#$pass defined earlier. that's input
$password_hash=crypt($pass, '$2a$07$'.$salt.'');
if (crypt($password_hash, $ex_password)==$ex_password) {
 #everything is ok
} else {
 #username/password combination doesn't exists
 $msgText = "Oops! Check your username and password";
 $pass=NULL;
}
```

I still get an error 'Oops! Check your username and password'. I check database and output from `$password_hash` and they match. 
Maybe it's better to code like this:

```
#.....
if ($password_hash==$ex_password){}
#.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass the user input to the crypt function when checking passwords (see the [`crypt` docs](http://php.net/crypt)):

```
if (crypt($user_input, $hashed_password) == $hashed_password) {
   echo "Password verified!";
}
```

You are currently calculating a new (different) password hash and compare it with the one that's stored.

Comment: so I don't need to store salt in database?

Comment: Not separately. It's already stored as part of the password digest (the last part between the dollar signs)

Answer (score 2):

Why are your encryting $password_hash twice?

I would think your comparison would be more like this:

```
$password_hash=crypt($pass, '$2a$07$'.$salt);
$password_hash_check($ex_password, '$2a$07$' . $salt);
if ($password_hash === $password_hash_check) {
 #everything is ok
} else {
 #username/password combination doesn't exists
 $msgText = "Oops! Check your username and password";
 $pass=NULL;
}
```

Comment: Your code example is somehow flawed. Maybe missing a `=crypt`? Even then, it's unlikely to work (see the docs)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want:

```
$password_hash=crypt($pass, '$2a$07$'.$salt.''); // crypt input
if ($password_hash== $ex_password) // check against crypted 
                                   // password stored in the database
```